# How do I select sets of nodes with a single XPath query?

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to extract journey and price information from my favorite airline.

I have a search results page that looks like this:

[MASwings search results http://img28.imagevenue.com/aAfkjfp01fo1i-2846/loc29/42467_dayview_oneway_122_29lo.jpg](http://img28.imagevenue.com/aAfkjfp01fo1i-2846/loc29/42467_dayview_oneway_122_29lo.jpg)

EDIT: Image host might have blocked the hotlink. See the image on this page: http://img28.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=42467_dayview_oneway_122_29lo.jpg

[Repro URL for booking query](https://book.maswings.com.my/itd/itd/maswings/lang/en/travel/quotes?journeyCount=1&search=JOURNEY&departDate0=2011-03-27&departLocation0=Airport.MYY&arriveLocation0=Airport.LBU&numAdults=1&fareClass=Economy&step=Search)

I can select each row that represents a flight using this XPath selector:

```
//*[@class="servicecode "]/ancestor::tr[1]
```

But each flight row is not an independent journey; the flights are really grouped into legs, and these are what I want to select.

The row class alternates for each new leg: the rows of the first leg have class "datarow", and the rows of the next leg have "datarow alt". In Python I can group the nodes selected by the above expression using `itertools.groupby`, but if there is a way to acheive this purely in XPath, I would prefer it.

An extension to this question: my selector selects all rows, whether the flight is sold out or not. I can select the first flight of every bookable journey using this selector:

```
//*[contains(@class, "datarow")][.//input]
```

But if the leg has more than one flight, then I will have to look for following sibling with the same class using another XPath query.

Is there a single XPath query that will return me each bookable leg as a nodeset?

Note: I'm using the Python lxml library, in case that matters.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for solutions to your two problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> I can select each row that represents a flight using this XPath selector:
>
>      //*[@class="servicecode "]/ancestor::tr[1] 
>
> But each flight row is not an independent journey; the flights are really grouped into legs, and these are what I want to select.
>
> The row class alternates for each new leg: the rows of the first leg have class "datarow",
> ```

**Use**:

```
//tr[@class='datarow'][.//*[@class='servicecode']]
```

> An extension to this question: my
>   selector selects all rows, whether the
>   flight is sold out or not. I can
>   select the first flight of every
>   bookable journey using this selector:
>
> ```
> //*[contains(@class, "datarow")][.//input]
> ```
>
> But if the leg has more than one
>   flight, then I will have to look for
>   following sibling with the same class
>   using another XPath query.
>
> Is there a single XPath query that
>   will return me each bookable leg as a
>   nodeset?

**Yes**:

```
  (//tr[@class='datarow'])[1]//input 
| 
  (//tr[@class='datarow'])[1]
         //following-sibling::tr[@class='datarow altrow']
                   [count(preceding-sibling::tr[@class='datarow'])=1]
                         //input
```

This XPath expression selects all `tr` elements that represent each bookable leg (in this case 3 legs) of the first journey.

To get all legs of the second journey, substitute `1` in the above expression with `2`.

To get all legs of the k-th journey, substitute `1` in the above expression with the actual value of `k`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dimitre! I'm afraid I gave the wrong XPath selector for my second example (I copied the same selector from the first example). I have edited this now; could you update your answer? Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: +1 For quickly understand the question: selecting by group between siblings.

Comment: Sorry, Dimitre, I think you may have misunderstood me. Perhaps I didn't explain very well. But based on your answer I have hacked together something that works; please see my answer. I don't understand why it works, and I don't know if this is the best way to get the results I want.

Comment: @isme: It is bad to add new information as an answer to your own question. Think why you needed twice to explain more and more -- that means that you were not able to define your question well. Therefore, do not to hurry to modify the question again. Maybe now you understand your initial problem and its solution, but a new problem arized. In this case, ask the new problem as a new question. Finally, if an answer contributed significantly for finding the solution, according to SO's good ettiquette, you are expected to accept that answer and also to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

This does what I want. But is there a more elegant solution?

```
//*[contains(@class, "columns")]//tr[contains(@class, "datarow")][1]
|
//*[contains(@class, "columns")]//tr[not(contains(@class, "altrow"))]
       [preceding-sibling::tr[1]
           [contains(@class, "altrow")]]
|
//*[contains(@class, "columns")]//tr[contains(@class,"altrow")]
       [preceding-sibling::tr[1]
           [not(contains(@class, "altrow"))]]
```

The second part selects each set of consecutive rows with class not containing "altrow" as a single nodeset.

The third part selects each set of consecutive rows with class containing "altrow" as a single node set.

The first part selects the first set of consecutive rows with class not containing "altrow", because it is not selected by the second part.

Comment: Actually, this one works in FirePath (visual XPath debugger for Firefox), and not in lxml; lxml isn't returning the nodes as groups, but singly. I could achieve the same thing much more simply, and I'm back where I started!